# mysql select timestamps with rounded/full hour

Tags: mysql, select, timestamp

I would like to know how to make sql query to select timestamps where timestamps are rounded/full hours.

Timestamps in mysql:

```
1534251600
1534252500
1534253400
1534254300
1534255200
1534256100
1534257000
1534257900
1534258800
1534259700
1534260600
1534261500
1534262400
1534263300
1534264200
1534265100
1534266000
1534266900
1534267800
1534268700
```

I get new sql entry every 15 min but I would like to display data only for rows where timestamp is rounded hour.

Comment: What to you mean with rounded hour? is it a hour with zero minutes and zero seconds?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get new sql entry every 15 min but I would like to display data only
>   for rows where timestamp is rounded hour.

If you mean a hour with zero minutes and zero seconds is a rounded hour.

You can do

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 table
WHERE
   (MINUTE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp_column)) = 0) 
 AND 
   (SECOND(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp_column)) = 0)
```

see explainment demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/340e01/514

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need only the timestamps which represent the times like N hours 00 minutes, the query you're looking for is:

```
SELECT * FROM <table>
WHERE
MINUTE(FROM_UNIXTIME(<timestamp_column>)) = 0 AND 
SECOND(FROM_UNIXTIME(<timestamp_column>)) = 0
```